# Pass values from javascript into rails code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Can I pass values from javascript into rails code ?? Here my example:

```
<script>
function upload_fun() {
        $.ajax({
            url : '/upload',
            datatype : 'json',
            data :{
                file : file,
            },
            success : function(data_get) {
               console.log(data_get)
               #example: data_get = "1234"
            },
     });
}
</script>
<div>
   #I wan't to put data_get in javascript to rails code like this: 
   <% @data = Data.find_by_dataname(:dataname => "data_get")%>
</div>
```

Can I pass value like that?

Comment: No, in short - JavaScript is evaluated at client side (in browser), ERB (html templating in Rails) is evaluated at server side. They are not directly connected.

Comment: You can create a method in your respective controller to receive value from ajax call. Not sure how you intend to use it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that returns a ready-made HTML and then injecct ($().append()) it into your main file.

There's a guide for working with JS in Rail: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: oh you want to do it the other way around :D
Well I'll leave this answer anyway, even though it's wrong.

You can store values in data html attribute.

```
<div id="user" data-name="<%= @user.name %>">
</div>
```

And then read it using jQuery like this.

```
var name = $("#user").data("name");
```

If you are using older jQuery than 1.4.3 you will have to use a bit longer syntax.

```
var name = $("#user").attr("data-name");
```